# jQuery find value by id inside a div

Tags: jquery, find, hide, element

So i have a few divs that look like this:

```
<div class="offerEntity">
    <h2 id="title">some title</h2>
</div>
```

and on search they update depending on the value of `<h2 id="title">`. On the input on key up it triggers an event which finds if the value of the search box matches( substring search ) of each of the divs. The problem is I cannot manage to get the `<h2>` value.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#search_box').keyup(function () {
        value = $('#search_box').attr('value');
        //trim left
        $(".offerEntity").each(function(i) {
            if($(i).attr('value').toLowerCase().indexOf(value) < 0){ // this is wrong
                // hide div
            }
        });
    });
});
```

So if the condition matches i want to hide the whole `<div class="offerEntity">`

Comment: For starters if you have multiple Div's like that then I'm wondering if you have duplicate ID values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the 'value' of h2 contained within `.offerEntity` like so:

```
var searchValue = $('#search_box').attr('value'),
    headerValue;

$(".offerEntity").each(function(){

    headerValue = $(this).find('h2').text();

    if(headerValue == searchValue){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```